# Connected App: How to select a Custom Attribute for SAML Service Provider Settings

Tags: saml

At the bottom of the Connected App Details Page I created a simple Custom Attribute:

[image]

It's fairly simple, I just wanted to test and get the Nickname.

Now, when I go edit the Connected App Policy, I'm not able to select a Custom Attribute.  In fact, I only get the option of None:

[image]

What step am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Is it not possible to have something other than None, in the Custom Attribute ComboBox (after selecting Custom Attribute for Subject Type)?  This is odd.

Comment: It looks like I discovered the holy grail of questions, something that is so hard and misunderstood that no one on earth knows.  Yay me!

Comment: Experiencing the same issue here. It is very odd.

Comment: When trying to make the change using sfdx, I get the following error `Error parsing file: 'CustomAttr' is not a valid value for the enum 'SamlSubjectType' (14:54)` even though the docs clearly state that it is the enum for the selection `https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_connectedapp.htm`

Answer (score 1):

IMO, this is super confusing. The Custom Attribute option allows you to select a field on the user object and is not related to the Connected App's Custom Attributes section.

Create a custom field on the user object that aligns with the Subject that you need and it should be selectable in the Custom Attribute picklist on the connected app.